# The GPU memory is not enough when computing feature centers using pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, out-of-memory, gpu, vision

I want use the class feature centers in the loss function when using pytorch. But when I compute the centers, the GPU memory is not enough. How can I solve it? The code is as follows:

```
for epoch in range((args.start_epoch+1), args.epochs):
  Center= computer_Center(model,dataloader, classnum)
    for input, target in train_loader:
        target = target.cuda()
        input = input.cuda()
        input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)
        target_var = torch.autograd.Variable(target)
        outputs, feature = model(input_var)
        l = criterion(feature,target_var, Center) .forward()
        l.backward(retain_graph=True)


def computer_Center(model,dataloader, classnum):
    model.train()
    for i in range(classnum):
            j=0
            for input,target in dataloader:
                target=target.cuda()
                input = input.cuda()
                input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(input)
                target=torch.autograd.Variable(target)
                _, feature_ext = model(input_var)
                ind=torch.where(target==i)[0]
                if ind.shape[0]>0:
                    if j==0:
                        feature_mid = feature_ext[ind, :]
                        feature_sum_mid=feature_mid.sum(0)
                    else:
                        feature_mid = feature_ext[ind, :]
                        feature_sum_mid = feature_sum_mid+feature_mid.sum(0)
                    j=j+1

            feature_sum_mid=feature_sum_mid.unsqueeze(0)
            if i==0:
                feature_sum=feature_sum_mid
            else:
                feature_sum=torch.cat([feature_sum,feature_sum_mid],dim=0)

    Center=feature_sum
    for i in range(7):
            Center[i,:]=feature_sum[i,:]/ClaSamNum[i]

return Center
```

Comment: You can use google colaboratory to use google's computing power for your training and testing. You can also use hardware accelerator for your program on colaboratory with their's GPU or TPU

Comment: whats your batch size ?

Comment: `l.backward(retain_graph=True)` may be this one causing memory issue

Comment: The batch size is 70. It not matters. I want to use Center in every training epoch.

Comment: It would be better if you can come up with a more minimal example or explain what you're trying to do; i.e. where the error occurs. Assuming it happens in `computer_Center`, the issue is most likely that you're never freeing gpu memory; to compute the gradient with respect to `feature_sum_mid`, torch needs to keep track of all the previous operations that have led to it. in this case, it _might_ be equivalent to loading your whole dataset into gpu memory. Otherwise, the `retain_graph=True` looks suspicious too